# return an iterator to a private variable that can be used with this inside member function

Tags: c++, class, iterator, this, constants

I want to be able to make a method like

```
void Vector<T>::foo()
{
  std::transform(this->begin(),this->end(),this->begin(), lambda)
}
```

but if I make my begin/end functions const they return a const_iterator, else I can`t use them with this while inside member function. Is  there a way to do it?

```
 template <class T>
    class Vector 
        {
        public:
            Vector(std::vector<T> coords) : _coords(coords) {}
            class std::vector<T>::iterator begin() const { return _coords.begin(); }
            class std::vector<T>::iterator end() const { return _coords.end(); }
        private:
            std::vector<T> _coords;
        };
```

I want to be able to use this->begin() inside a function

Comment: Why do you prepend `class` to the return types of your member functions?

Comment: @vahancho: usually `typename`, as `iterator` is dependent name. `typename` and `class` in template parameter can be interchanged since C++17. OP probably do that in here, even if it is a non acceptable place.

Comment: Provide non const overload? (BTW const overload should `return const_iterator`)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you need const and non const overload:

```
template <class T>
class Vector 
{
public:
    Vector(std::vector<T> coords) : _coords(coords) {}
    auto begin() const { return _coords.begin(); }
    auto end() const { return _coords.end(); }
    auto begin() { return _coords.begin(); }
    auto end() { return _coords.end(); }
    auto cbegin() const { return _coords.cbegin(); }
    auto cend() const { return _coords.cend(); }

    template <typename F>
    void foo(F f)
    {
        std::transform(cbegin(), cend(), begin(), f);
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> _coords;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you provide a `const` qualified overload

```
template <class T>
class Vector 
    {
    public:
        using iterator = typename std::vector<T>::iterator;
        using const_iterator = typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator;

        Vector(std::vector<T> coords) : _coords(coords) {}

        iterator begin() { return _coords.begin(); }
        iterator end() { return _coords.end(); }

        const_iterator begin() const { return _coords.begin(); }
        const_iterator end() const { return _coords.end(); }
    private:
        std::vector<T> _coords;
    };
```

Comment: I think OP would want the non-`const` variants to be private.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: As `Foo` is also a member method of `Vector`, visibility can be changed.

Comment: Works wonderful, just a question, if i comment out the non const functions I get the error "you cannot assign to a variable that is non-const" but this is a *const vector inside foo() right? Why does it need a non const overload to work properly?

Comment: @SonOfEvil you can't modify the `T` pointed to by a `const_iterator` (it's like `const T *`), but you can for an `iterator` (it's like `T *`). `std::transform` is roughly `for (; first != last; ++first, ++d_first) *d_first = f(*first);`, i.e. it is modifying the elements pointed to by the third parameter